# Making combinations

Tags: python, combinatorics, cartesian-product

I am a beginner in Python and I need a help with this task:

I have a a list with unknown number of characters that have a following form:

```py
my_list = ["t1v1", "t1v2", "t2v1", "t2v2", "t2v3"]
```

`t` stands for a test and `v` stands for a version of the test. I would like to get all possible combinations between tests. In this case I will have 2x3=6 combinations of tests.

```py
combinations = ["t1v1_t2v1", "t1v1_t2v2", "t1v1_t2v3", "t1v2_t2v1", "t1v2_t2v2", "t1v2_t2v3"]
```

I cannot make combinations within a test, for example `"t1v1_t1v2"`is not possible. Moreover, I can have more tests, not just two as in this example.

How can I do this, please?

Comment: If you have three tests would you want to include combinations of three? e.g. `t1v1_t2v1_t3v2`? Or just all of the pairings like `t1v1_t2v1`, `t1v1_t3v2` etc.?

Comment: @Stuart the first one, so `t1v1_t2v1_t3v2`. thanks!

Comment: These are **not combinations**. You want to group the inputs by test number, and then perform a Cartesian product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for this. The following code should work for any number of tests:

```
from itertools import product, groupby

tests = ["t1v1", "t1v2", "t2v1", "t2v2", "t2v3", "t3v1", "t3v2"]
# group the lists into lists of lists containing items of single test
lists = [list(l) for _, l in groupby(tests, lambda x: x[:2])]
output = list('_'.join(x) for x in product(*lists))
```

here `output` is -

```
['t1v1_t2v1_t3v1', 't1v1_t2v1_t3v2', 't1v1_t2v2_t3v1', 't1v1_t2v2_t3v2', 't1v1_t2v3_t3v1', 't1v1_t2v3_t3v2', 't1v2_t2v1_t3v1', 't1v2_t2v1_t3v2', 't1v2_t2v2_t3v1', 't1v2_t2v2_t3v2', 't1v2_t2v3_t3v1', 't1v2_t2v3_t3v2']
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Separated lists can be done using

groupby_result = groupby(my_list, lambda v: v[0:2])
lists = [list(v) for _, v in groupby_result]

Answer (score 2):

First, I would separate the test list data into different groups based on their test number, then I would product all the different lists of each test number. Both will be achieved using `groupby` and `product` function from `itertools`

```py
from itertools import groupby, product

def get_test_number(test_string):
  return test_string[0:2]

my_list = ["t1v1", "t1v2", "t2v1", "t2v2", "t2v3"]
groupby_result = groupby(my_list, get_test_number)
separated_tests = [list(v) for _, v in groupby_result]
products = product(*separated_tests)
strings_of_products = list(map("_".join, products))
print(strings_of_products)
```

Comment: whats `d` and `p` ? You did not define it before

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. I have changed my variables names for better understanding